# IPV6 socket design in python

Tags: python, windows, ipv6

I wrote this a while back for IPV4 sockets:

```
    h = self.cb.get()
    t = self.text.get()
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        sock.connect((h, 5554))
        sock.sendall(bytes(t,'ascii'))
        if self.addr_append(h) == 0: 
            self.cb['values'] = self.cb['values'] + tuple([h])
    except:
       print('gui socket send/connect: ',sys.exc_info()[0], " > ",sys.exc_info()[1])
    finally:
        sock.close()
```

With Error Message:

> >  [WinError 10051] A socket operation was
>   attempted to an unreachable network

Using IPV4 encapsulation (i.e. ::ffff: IPV4 ADDRESS) I get the error:

> >  [WinError 10049] The requested address is not
>   valid in its context

The second error I think is because windows doesn't like my compatibility settings for IPV4 to IPV6, however, this doesn't answer why it won't work on the first case. Am I implementing IPV6 incorrectly? It works for IPV4.

EDIT: I put the characters in the ::ffff: inside a URL comment accidentally.

UPDATE:

I tried socket.create_connection and I still get:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\VMWare\Desktop\Attack.py", line 49, in buttonClick
    sock = socket.create_connection((h, 12839))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 435, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 426, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

I'm thinking I'll give up on this for now and come back to it unless anyone has other ideas.

Comment: Is `::ffff:` supposed to be an IPv4 address represented in [6to4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4) format?

Comment: @Mike: It is an IPv4-Mapped IPv6 address: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.5.2

Comment: Why don't you just use `socket.create_connection` and let Python worry about details like this?